# Pagination in modx revolution with different page limits for different pages

Tags: php, pagination, modx-revolution, getresource

I was working with getResources and getPages for pagination. Now, I have a requirement that the first page has 6 child Resources and the further pages have 9 child Resources each. I tried manipulating with the limit parameter, but didn't get the results. Is there some way or the other to do the thing using getResources and getPages? Any other method that can be helpful as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&pageOneLimit` can be used to set different page limit for first page. it is added in the get page version 1.2.2-pl.so upgrade it use it..

```
[[!getPage? &element=getResources &limit=9 &pageOneLimit=6 &tpl=whatever ]]
```

Comment: Could you please provide me with the link of the details of the above.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass a parameter via GET in a URL link to the page to allow the user to select between viewing 10, 20, or all results.

```
<a href="[[~[[*id]]? &limit=`10`]]">see 10 per page</a> | 
<a href="[[~[[*id]]? &limit=`20`]]">see 20 per page</a> |
<a href="[[~[[*id]]? &limit=`0`]]">see all</a>
```

Where [[*id]] is the page that you're on which contains the "getPage" snippet call.

Answer (score 0):

go to rtfm.modx.com and lookup "IF" under the plugins - it's basically an if statement for modx tags. I would think that maybe you could find some condition within your pages that you could set your getresources limit on. basically :

```
[[!getResources? &limit=`[[!if? &subject=`[[+currentpage]]` &operator=`!=` &operand=`1` then=`6` &else=`9`]]` &tpl=`whatever`]]
```

You'll have to check the syntax - I just winged that off the top of my head & also you'll have to investigate how the pagination figures out what page it's on to get the correct variable for the subject - but I think you should be able to do it like that.

-sean

**UPDATE**

You could probably do it like this:

[[!getPage? 
     &element=`getResources`
          &limit=`[[!if? 
                    &subject=`[[+page]]
                    `&operator=`!=
                    `&operand=`1
                    `&then=`6
                    `&else=`9
          `]]` 
     &tpl=`whatever`
]]

However getPage also has a limit attribute & I have no idea how it differentiates between it's attributes and it's element attributes. The docs appear to be confusing here. 
The +page variable is default as in the docs & it looks like you can change it with the pageVarkey attribute. 
Again, off the top of my head, check the syntax and docs before trying.

Comment: Thank you Sean. This doesn't give me results. But I still believe that the IF plugin would somehow work(I have installed it as well and tried the part of code you guided of also). Could you please also guide me how to use it with getPage and getResources together?

Comment: Hi Sean. I tried exactly the same as you have said in your update. But the 'limit' attribute takes a constant value and not a conditional value as we both have tried. I went through the snippet code of getPage. It actually calculates the total number of records, the total number of pages, and designates the page limit value then to the pages. So, it doesn't take the effective value of the conditional statement.
Is there any variations of the above method or any other way that I can try out?